# How to access files in a mounted persistent disk through a new VM on GCP?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine, mount, google-persistent-disk

I have created a new VM on GCP with mounting to a persistent disk that contains some files that I want to access.
To check where is the path of the mounted disk, I created another VM that no additional disk was mounted.
However, by using `df` command, I cannot find the path of the mounted disk because the disks visible to both VMs are the same, as below.

[image]

[image]

May I know how to

1. make the mounted disk visible?
2. access the files on the disk without formating?

Comment: There might be many reasons for this issue but these two are the primary reasons:

Attaching a disk of unknown partition type Ensure proper mounting of the disk.

To troubleshoot these issues, you first need to run the following command.

```
lsbk or fdisk -l
```

These two commands will list all the partitions that are attached to your VM or instance. Now, from the list you can find names like sda, sdb, sdc etc.,

Comment: sda will be the primary partition, while sdb and sdc are the secondary volumes or persistent disks which you have attached to your VM. In your case as you have attached only a single disk it will be sdb.

Up to this point, you have only attached your persistent disk to your VM, but that doesn’t mean its mounted to the file system. Follow the below steps for mounting the disk to your file system.

Comment: Create a mount point for mounting your disk. This will be the path where you can access your files. The command below will help you create the mount point.

```
mkdir /mnt/test
```

feel free to create this directory at your desired location and you can also name it accordingly.

After creating the directory try to attach the disk to your file system by using the below command

```
mount /dev/sdb /mnt/test
```

Comment: Now you can access your files if there is no issue with the partition type etc., if you get any error stating that `unsupported partition type` try to use some recovery software or check which OS will support that partition type and mount this disk to a VM loaded with that particular OS.

Comment: This [blog](https://medium.com/@abogam78/attaching-persistent-disk-to-an-instance-on-google-cloud-platform-gcp-c73b6ec18ec9) written by **Abogam** contains similar information on how to attach a persistent disk to your VM in gcp, refer to it for detailed information.

Comment: [This page in the GCP doc](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/disk-symlinks) explains how to identify attached but unmounted disks. 

Try `ls /dev/disk/by-id`, what is the output? Can you use the info in the doc I posted to identify  the disk you added ?